# Did I handle this post properly?

Tags: discussion

I DV'd (along with others) and voted to close because the question showed no effort on the OP's part. Within a minute he posted an answer to his own question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120345/how-to-get-all-but-the-closest-using-jquery

Comment: The question text does tell you he was planning to self-answer. It's not a good question though (it is asking for 'the best way'). I've voted to close it.

Comment: "Best" is pretty much open-ended - needs to be qualified with some constraints. Bad question.

Comment: Now the OP has deleted the question :-/

Comment: See also: [What can be done to improve moderation of self-answered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137353) and [Is it generally frowned upon to answer your own question immediately?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172608), the gist of both being "the question must be good, independent of the answer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say yes.

The poster could have completely avoided the situation with the "Answer your own question" button, which submits the answer and the question at the same time.  *Based on the gap you described, this didn't happen.*  This method of asking shows everyone that the author's intention is that the question be self-answered.  This is the entire purpose of that button and why it is best to use it.

---

In addition, as Oded and Jay Blanchard pointed out, the question would qualify as *primarily opinion based*, so that would definitely be grounds to close and downvote the question.

Comment: Self answering may be the intention, but a bad question is a bad question that should be closed, regardless of the OP answering it.

Comment: @Oded True, but I thought that self-answered questions had some leniency for being too broad, which it seems that question was.  Other close reasons should, of course, be used regardless, but it seems as though the majority of self-answered questions would be too broad on their own.  I could also be completely wrong on this.

Comment: The other part of this, as @Oded pointed out before, is, even with leniency, asking for a 'best' method is a bad question because it is soliciting opinion.

Comment: Self answered questions have no leniency. They're subject to the same standards as questions you're expecting other people to answer.

Comment: @JayBlanchard You're right.  I was too focused on it being too broad.